# Is protobuf for C++ available on Nuget?

Tags: c++, package, nuget

this might seem like a question easily answered with a google search but I assure you, for me, it is not.

I am trying to determine if an up-to-date protocol buffer package from google exists on Nuget. I tried downloaded what *seemed* like the protobuf package ([here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf/)) but it is version 2.5.0. I am a stickler for currency and for that reason would *really really* like to use the most up-to-date version. Not to mention the ease of keeping libraries up to date with nuget...

I have downloaded the master branch from github, and generated some messages with protoc.exe. The problem is that when I include these messages, VS2015 complains about missing header files. I have concluded that the version of protobuf available on nuget is too far behind the current version and does not support proto3... Again, I am a stickler for currency.

Now the real complexity arises from the fact that there are in fact *many* packages on Nuget that seem to be "the real" protobuf.

So to put it bluntly, is there a *current* protobuf package available on nuget for c++?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, latest version is not available as compiled NuGet package. There is an [Issue #1154](https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/1154) in the official google/protobuf project about it. Comment there to follow-up the problem.